# Uploading large files in SQL azure

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Can anybody help me in understanding how to upload large files in SQL azure using block.
I am not able to find any good implementation of Blocks to upload files in SQL azure.

Thanks,
Ashwani

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at storing large files in Azure BLOB Storage.  You will end up running out of size in your SQL Azure database, or put yourself into a more expensive SQL Azure price point, by storing files in your relational database.  You can always store the pointer to your BLOB in your relational database.